# Empty Array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, variables

I am trying to create an empty array in Swift that the user adds on to. It is a very small class because I am just starting a new file. I am using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=war0gHL26ns/this) tutorial for my project which is what the code is based off. Here is the code I tried (It didn't work):

```
var tasks = task[]()
```

Here is all of my code in case it is needed:

```
class TaskManager: NSObject {

    var tasks = task[]()

    func addTask(name: String){
        tasks.append(task(name: name))
    }
}
```

There is an error on the `var tasks = task[]()` line saying: "Array types are now written the brackets around the element type". I am unsure of how to fix the problem.

How can one create an empty array?

Any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the array in this way:

```
var tasks = [task]()
```

It changed in swift from the tutorial you are watching.

Comment: Both answers helped but I felt this one was easier to understand. I will vote up both but accept this answer. Thanks @Dario.

Answer (score 2):

The syntactic sugar for an array of Type is [Type] in Swift. You can create an empty array of Tasks like this:

```
class Task{}
var tasks = [Task]()
```